# Sum of elements in nested list using a list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to calculate the sum of elements that are positive in each nested list.

```
    data = [[10, 6, -1, 2, -4, 3, -10, -3, -2, 4],
    [0, -3, -9, -1, 2, 6, -5, 8, -7, 0],
    [-2, -10, -2, -7, 8, 0, 1, 0, 8, -5]]

    sum_l = 0
    sum_list : list = list()
    sum_list = [[(sum_l+=y) for y in x] for x in data if y > 0]
```

I write it like this, but it gives an error: invalid syntax in (sum_l+=y). How do I fix it, and how to use list comprehensions correctly in general?

Thanks!

Comment: don't white assign statements inside list comprehension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) to sum the inner lists:

```
data = [[10, 6, -1, 2, -4, 3, -10, -3, -2, 4],
        [0, -3, -9, -1, 2, 6, -5, 8, -7, 0],
        [-2, -10, -2, -7, 8, 0, 1, 0, 8, -5]]

result = [sum(e for e in lst if e > 0) for lst in data]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[25, 16, 17]
```

**Resources**:

- [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: Thank you! It`s work!

Comment: @hello_w Glad I could help! If you found my answer helpful please consider marking it as [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) to signal others that your issue was solved.